# How to serve php pages without allowing them to be downloadable?

Tags: php, apache

I have a question about apache servers on linux:
how to let apache use a .php file to serve the corresponding http page and still prevent the same .php file from beeing downloadable with wget, by third parties ?

I guess this could involve file ownership, file permissions, php configuration and apache configuration.

Here is what I had before discovering that my php code was exposed:

I have Apache 2.4.37 installed on a centos 8 server, together with PHP 7.2.33

I have a hello world test.php php file in /var/www/html

```
$ls-l 
-rw-r--r--.  1 root   root         75 31 août   2020 test.php
```

When
I do

1. go to siteurl/test.php with firefox,
   I get the hello world message echoed normally.

The issue is that I am able to download the source code from another computer doing
2)

```
wget 'siteurl/test.php'
```

in the terminal
I feel it is not very safe, because database credentials can be in php files like config.php; and in general I want to hide my code, if possible.

I tried to solve the issue editing httpd.conf:

I added the following lines

```
<Files ~ "\.php$>
<RequireAll>
    Require all denied
    Require not user apache
</RequireAll>
</Files>
```

(User and Group are set to apache)

I restarted httpd
Now
when I do 1),
I get the message

> Forbidden
> You don't have permission to access /test.php on this server."

when I do 2), I get a 403 error.

So the problem is not really solved,

I would like 1) to behave as before and 2) to behave as it is behaving right now.

Thank you for your help,

best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your apache.conf contain these lines?

```
AddHandler php-script .php
AddType text/html .php
```

They should tell Apache that php scripts should be handled by the PHP module, and not downloaded like other files.

Your Require rules are denying access to all URLs with a .php extension, not just preventing their download. That's the wrong solution for what you're trying to achieve.